# My K570UD laptop does not have asus::kbdbacklight!

Tags: 18.04, asus, keyboard-backlight

Actually i can't change the keyboard backlight in my laptop Asus K570UD 
and when i search under 
**/sys/class/leds/**
and NO asus::kbdbacklight
Can anyone help me?

```
$ lsmod | grep asus
asus_nb_wmi 28672 0 
asus_wmi 32768 1 asus_nb_wmi 
sparse_keymap 16384 1 asus_wmi 
asus_wireless 20480 0
wmi 32768 4 asus_wmi,wmi_bmof,mxm_wmi,nouveau 
video 49152 3 asus_wmi,i915,nouveau
```

Comment: Please show the list of loaded kernel modules - add output of `lsmod | grep asus` to the question.

Comment: @N0rbert hi thank you for your respond

`asus_nb_wmi            28672  0`
`asus_wmi               32768  1 asus_nb_wmi`
`sparse_keymap          16384  1 asus_wmi`
`asus_wireless          20480  0`
`wmi                    32768  4 asus_wmi,wmi_bmof,mxm_wmi,nouveau`
`video                  49152  3 asus_wmi,i915,nouveau`

Comment: This specifi model has no keyboard backlight probably. Do you have a backlight button on the keyboard?

Comment: @Pilot6 Hi thank you for your respond and YES!!! It's **ALWAYS** on

Answer (score 0):

I just get my laptop to Asus Services and they fixed it 
the backlight wasn't working even in windows 10 with ATKDriver
After that it works like charm....